# Undefined control sequence when including pdfpages package

Tags: errors, pdf, pdfpages

**Problem:**

I try to include the following packages in my .tex file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

**For this I get the following errors:**

```
thesis.tex (line 186)
Undefined control sequence (\mainmatterSU ...)
```

**I Google a bit and find this:** https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings#Undefined_control_sequence

Which tells me that it might be a typo, but then I open up the .cls file and check there, which gives me:

```
% MAINMATTER
\newcommand{\mainmatterSU}{

\begingroup
\cleardoublepage
\edef\x{\endgroup
\noexpand\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{\the\value{page}}%
}%
\x

\cleardoublepage

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont\thepage}}
}   % re-define plain page

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

So I'm going a bit insane over here because I don't see the miss-spelling or what I could have done wrong by just including a package.

Removing those two packages will remove the errors.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error message you show is not from tex and does not show which command is not defined. Please edit the question to add the exact error from the log file, from `!` to `?`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Texpad for OS X and I can't seem to locate ! to ?, which you are referring to. Could I kindly ask for some assistance?

Comment: If your main file is `zzz.tex` then latex will have left a `zzz.log` file which will contain the error message all tex errors start with `!` and end with `?` (in interactive mode you can type a response to the `?` but the `?` is printed anyway even if your editor runs tex in batch mode)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the explanation. But no log file exist in the same folder as the .tex file after compilation. I have uploaded the entire package here: http://distans.hkr.se/fam/latexmall3.0.zip - try adding the above mentioned packages to the file thesis.tex and you will see the errors.

Comment: I'm not fetching the zip file but `edef\x{\endgroup
\noexpand\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{\the\value{page}}%
}%`  is not a safe use of `\edef` (especiiiially of `calc` package is being used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I found the log file. It was in a hidden folder. No idea why, but here it is: http://pastebin.com/aGK3csrF - tried to search for "mainmatter" but couldn't extract where the error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is

```
./thesis.tex:186: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next
                                                 {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.186 \mainmatter
```

so the undefined command is `\calc@next`

as I guessed in initial comment, the `\edef` usage is incorrect and `\setcounter` is not safe in that context, although the error is usually not detected if `calc` is not loaded. put `\noexpand` before `\setcounter`

Comment: Thanks, this solved it perfectly. Highly appreciate your time and commitment to solve this issue!