# Including xifthen package breaks macro expansion in header

Tags: errors, undefined, xifthen, calc

In the following MWE, I build a 'database' which I then query later in body text and in headers.

It works fine until I load the `xifthen` package. This is not used in the MWE, but I do use the `\isempty{}` feature it provides elsewhere in my real file.

With some searching I found this similar problem (i.e. same error message): [Undefined control sequence when including pdfpages package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199158/undefined-control-sequence-when-including-pdfpages-package) but adding `\noexpand` before the (second) `\setcounter` didn't fix the problem.

Error (log file seems empty for some reason):

[image]

Can someone suggest a fix (ideally) other than working around `xifthen`?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen}        % PROBLEMATIC PACKAGE (ifthen works)    

% Database counter
\newcounter{awcounter}

% Database creation command
\newcommand{\awset}[3]{% #1 specifies the Aw document number, #2 the field, and #3 the value
    \setcounter{awcounter}{#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname aw#2\roman{awcounter}\endcsname{#3}%
}

% Build database for Aw no. 9
\awset{9}{ruler}{RULER}

% Database retrieval command
\newcommand{\awruler}[1]{% #1 specifies the Aw document number
    \setcounter{awcounter}{#1}%
    \expandafter\csname awruler\roman{awcounter}\endcsname%
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}
Here is some text with a retrieval: \awruler{9}.

\section{Header with retrieval: \awruler{9}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your `\awruler` command is fragile so use `\protect\awruler`

Comment: you could also get rid of the `awcounter` and `\setcounter` commands and just use `\newcommand{\awruler}[1]{\csname awruler\romannumber#1\endcsname}` or `\newcommand{\awruler}[1]{\csname awruler#1\endcsname}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your definitions leaving them naturally robust and safe to use in a section heading:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage{xifthen}        % PROBLEMATIC PACKAGE (ifthen works)  (must be the authors:-)

% Database counter
%\newcounter{awcounter}

% Database creation command
\newcommand{\awset}[3]{% #1 specifies the Aw document number, #2 the field, and #3 the value
%    \setcounter{awcounter}{#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname aw#2#1\endcsname{#3}%
}

% Build database for Aw no. 9
\awset{9}{ruler}{RULER}

% Database retrieval command
\newcommand{\awruler}[1]{% #1 specifies the Aw document number
    \csname awruler#1\endcsname
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}
Here is some text with a retrieval: \awruler{9}.

\section{Header with retrieval: \awruler{9}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never liked the use of a counter, but it was code I borrowed and I didn't know of an alternative. Works like a charm on my end on the MWE, will try the main file and report back. I am puzzled, though, I thought that macro names couldn't contain digits (hence the roman conversion)? or is that exempted due to `csname` bracketing? (I've been very frustrated by not being able to create simple macros with digits at the end thus far and I've now tested that a call to `\awruler9` in my LaTeX code works just fine....

Comment: @K.G.Feuerherm `\awruler9` is `\awruler{9}` so works but of course you need the braces if there is more than one digit. `\awruler{10}`

Comment: Ah, I see. It is grabbing the token 9, rather than it being part of the macro name. I get it now!

Comment: Tested on main file with multiple records and fields, works fine!